# How can I output the ad efficiency from most to least?

Tags: javascript

How can I sort the brands from the most to least efficient using the given details?

```
 function calculateAdEfficiency(adCampaigns) {
    // The passed campaigns array from the test are the following:
    // { brand: 'Brand X', expenditure: 12345.89, customersGained: 4879 }
    // { brand: 'Brand Y', expenditure: 22456.17, customersGained: 6752 }
    // { brand: 'Brand Z', expenditure: 18745.36, customersGained: 5823 }

    // The efficiency is computed as (customersGained / expenditure) x 100.
    // Sort the ad efficiency according to the most to least efficient.

    
}
```

Comment: Considering you stated the rule to compute the efficiency (divide `customersGained` by `expenditure`), I don't quite get, what's your question exactly?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks for noticing sir.. given that computation already, I don't know how to output the most efficient to lease efficient

Comment: Can you please update your post, asking for how to sort based on efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this could help.

```
function calculateAdEfficiency(adCampaigns) {

    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i<adCampaigns.length; i++) {
        var current = adCampaigns[i];
        var brand = current.brand;
        var efficiency = (current.customersGained / current.customersGained)x100;
        result.push({brand: brand, efficiency: efficiency});
    }
    result.sort(function(a, b) {return b.efficiency - a.efficiency})
    return result;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is tackling your request. Consider that this is pure Javascript.

```js
function calculateAdEfficiency(adCampaigns) {
    adCampaigns.forEach(campaign => {
        var efficiency = 0
        if(campaign.expenditure > 0) {
            efficiency = (campaign.customersGained / campaign.expenditure) * 100
        }
        campaign.efficiency = efficiency;
    })
    adCampaigns.sort((v1, v2) => (v1.efficiency > v2.efficiency) ? -1 : 1);
    return adCampaigns;
}

var adCampaigns = [
    { brand: 'Brand X', expenditure: 12345.89, customersGained: 4879 },
    { brand: 'Brand Y', expenditure: 22456.17, customersGained: 6752 },
    { brand: 'Brand Z', expenditure: 18745.36, customersGained: 5823 },
]

console.log(calculateAdEfficiency(adCampaigns))
```